# ArgumentException when creating Bitmaps

Tags: c#, winforms, colors, bitmap, system.drawing

I am currently writing a programm, which creates colors and outputs them to a pictureBox. I am doing this in a 3D-for loop, to create all RGB colors. All this happens in a backgroundWorker. My code looks like this:

```
private void ColorWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
  Color color;
  String hex;
  Bitmap image;

  Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
  {
    progressBar1.Maximum = (255 * 255 * 255);
    progressBar1.Value = 0;
  });

  for (int r = 0; r <= 255; r++)
  {
    for (int g = 0; g <= 255; g++)
    {
      for (int b = 0; b <= 255; b++)
      {
        hex = "#FF" + r.ToString("X2") + g.ToString("X2") + b.ToString("X2");
        color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(hex);
        image = new Bitmap((int)nudWidth.Value, (int)nudHeight.Value);

        using (Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(image))
        using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(color))
        {
          gfx.FillRectangle(brush, 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height);
        }             

        Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
          pictureBox1.Image = image;
          progressBar1.Value++;
          label13.Text = progressBar1.Value + " / " + progressBar1.Maximum;
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am creating Bitmaps of the size 1920x1080. But after around 220 created images, I get `An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll` This also happens when using lower sizes, but then it takes longer to stop working. Is there an error in my code?

[image: Stack Trace]

InnerException is NULL

```
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Invalid Parameter.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

Comment: Is it possible you post the full exception including message, inner exceptions and stacktraces here? And please indicate on which line of your example code the exception occurs.

Comment: added some stuff hope it enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your memory usage in Task Manager when the application crashes - it is probably rather large.

Clean up the bitmaps each time - otherwise they are leaking something fierce.

```
Bitmap previousImage = null;
for(r... g... b...)
{
    // ...

    Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate
    {
            var previousImage = pictureBox1.Image;
        pictureBox1.Image = image;
        if (previousImage != null)
            previousImage.Dispose();
    });
}
```